# Which solvable Lie algebras / groups occur as Borel of semisimple Lie algebras / groups?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, solvable-groups

Let all Lie algebras have finite dimension, and let's first assume we are over $\mathbb C$. Then every semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ has Borel subalgebras (defined e.g. as maximal solvable subalgebras), and by well-known conjugacy theorems, the isomorphism class of those is uniquely determined by that of $\mathfrak g$. Actually, for any given root space decomposition

$$\mathfrak g = \mathfrak h \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in R} \mathfrak g_\alpha$$

and choice of positive roots, $$\displaystyle\mathfrak b := \mathfrak h \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in R^+} \mathfrak g_\alpha$$ is such a Borel.

Now I wondered, which solvable Lie algebras occur as Borels of semisimple $\mathfrak g$?
Of course you can say, I just answered that myself, because root systems / semisimple Lie algebras are classified, so if I go through the classification, I just wrote them all down.

But I am asking if there are some other criteria, in particular ones which are less obviously relying on the semisimple classification, which can identify the "possible Borels" *among the solvable Lie algebras* (whose general classification, I understand, is "wild").

As an example, all nilpotent Lie algebras are obviously excluded. Also, the above implies the following necessary criterion: For our solvable Lie algebra $L$, there has to exist a root system $R$ such that $\dim [L,L] = \frac12 \lvert R \rvert$ and $\mathrm{codim} [L,L] = rk(R)$. Which is sufficient for $\dim L \le 3$, but apparently already not in dimension $4$. Also, it still relies on our knowledge of root systems. But I am thinking vaguely in that direction, some combinatorial identities relating some invariants of $L$ (size of its nilradical in particular), which apparently must be fairly restrictive.

Another idea would be to look at the *automorphism group* of the Lie algebra in question, which I imagine might have a pretty "outstanding" structure for the "possible Borels".

---

As an upgrade of the question, of course we could look at fields different from $\mathbb C$; and, we can instead look at the analogous question for (Lie / algebraic) *groups*.

Comment: Somewhat related is [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159242/which-nilpotent-lie-algebras-appear-as-nilradicals-of-parabolic-subalgabras/161064#161064). We can first consider the nilradical of a Borel subalgebra and ask which Lie algebras can arise this way.

Comment: Related, but not related enough to be an answer. The question of how to decide which $p$-groups are Sylow $p$-subgroups of the finite simple groups is a tricky one. If one restricts oneself to so-called characteristic $p$-type simple groups(basically groups of Lie type in characteristic $p$) then one still can say very little completely abstractly. It was a lucky thing about CFSG that it didn't require too much $p$-group theory, or it probably still wouldn't be solved today.

Comment: A further remark from geometry. Milnor has asked which solvable Lie groups admit a left-invariant affine structure in "On Fundamental Groups of Complete Affinely Flat Manifolds". It turns out that in particular those solvable Lie groups do, whose Lie algebra arises as Borel of a semisimple Lie algebra.

Answer (score 2):

A general comment: such Lie algebras have the form $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{a}\ltimes\mathfrak{n}$, with the property that the central series is just $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{n},\mathfrak{n},\mathfrak{n},\dots)$. This is already a specific property; this property of the lower central series, to stabilize in 1 step, is equivalently restated as: every nilpotent quotient is abelian.

Moreover it has another restrictive property, namely that there exists an element of $\mathfrak{a}$ that acts on $\mathfrak{n}$ with only positive (real) eigenvalues (this implies the previous property), and even positive integral eigenvalues, and in a diagonalizable way.

Many 3-dimensional solvable Lie algebras are not of this form.